# Реализация внешнего trait для внешнего шаблона, параметризованного локальным типом в Rust

Tags: rust

После перехода с январьской версии компилятора Rust на beta. Обнаружил что код подобный этому не компилируется http://is.gd/oX7GWN:

```
use std::fmt::{Display, Formatter, Error};

struct MyLocalType;

type MyResult = Result<MyLocalType, String>;

impl Display for MyResult {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut Formatter) -> Result<(), Error> {
        f.write_str("some test string")
    }
}

fn main() { 
    let r: MyResult = Ok(MyLocalType); 
    println!("{}" , r); 
}
```

Это ошибка компилятора, или теперь внешние параметризованные типы нужно всегда "заворачивать" в свои ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ответ, скопированый с англоязычного stackoverflow:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29789877/can-not-implement-trait-from-another-crate-for-generic-type-from-another-crate-p
>
> There's no direct way to solve this for a pure alias like type.
>
> The code is the same as
>
> ```
> impl Display for Result<MyLocalType, String>
> ```
>
> and the compiler can't ensure that there will be no conflicting
>   implementations in other crates (aka, can't ensure that the
>   implementation is 'coherent'). Being able to do it is definitely
>   useful sometimes, but it was unfortunately a bug that the compiler
>   accepted it before.
>
> Solutions include:
>
> - defining a proper wrapper type for `Result`, e.g. `struct MyResult(Result<MyLocalType, String>);`,
> - defining your own enum: `enum MyResult { Ok(MyType), Err(String) }`,
> - define a wrapper type, but only use it when printing, i.e. write    `println!("{}", Wrapper(r)); instead of println!("{}", r);`.
>
> Both of these make MyResult a local type, and so the impl then should
>   be legal.

Описание на русском, как его понял я:

Теперь нет способа реализовывать типаж для стороннего обобщённого типа, пусть даже и параметризованного локальным типом. Так как компилятор не может быть уверен, что реализация будет согласована со всеми другими реализациями.

Чтобы решить эту проблему нужно сделать тип полностью локальным. Eсть несколько способов:

- «Обернуть» его в локальный тип-обёртку, например: `struct
  MyResult(Result<MyLocalType, String>);`
- Объявить свой собственный Result-подобный тип: `enum MyResult {
  Ok(MyType), Err(String) }`
- Или же обернуть его, но использовать обёртку только там, где необходим требуемый типаж, например: `println!("{}", Wrapper(r));` вместо `println!("{}", r);`

Comment: Было бы неплохо перевести ответ на русский.